# CSS nested div height 100% of screen instead of parent height

Tags: html, css

I have a div header which is fixed to the top of the page with a nested div. The div container has a height of 70px, a fixed height.

I want the nested div to have a height of 100% of the screen, not of the container div.

This is my code:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="nested">Content</div>
</div>
```

My css:

```
.header {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
} 

.nested {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

How can I get my nested div to be the height of the screen, not the container?

Comment: Have you tried 'position: fixed' on the nested element?

Comment: Is this question a joke? The nested div cannot be greater than 70px or it will break the rules set for the container one. If you want the nested one to fix the height of the screen it cannot be nested!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.header {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
} 

.nested {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 70px;
    height:100vh;
   background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/ek7zfzua/1/

Comment: Great! This is exactly what i'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For making the child div 100% in height, you will have to first let the parent div be 100%.
The child div cannot break open the boundaries of its parent and show up in complete screen unless the parent div boundaries are big enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `height:100vh` instead of percentage: https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/